# how to retrieve 2 specific rows from db in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, query-builder

I'm new to laravel. i have already searched the laravel doc site for this question. in one of my laravel view page i need to display the value of two rows

```
1) mtitle
2) mdescription
```

The table contains some more rows. the columns are `name,value,key,status`. i wrote the query builder in my blade.php using the model file like this.

```
$default = Specific::where('status',1)->where('name','mtitle')->first();
```

This obviously gets only one row. i want to know is there any way to get the other row 'mdescription' also without writing another one more query?

Comment: ,Do you mean to retrieve two rows ?

Comment: yes.. i need to get both named mtitle and mdescription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get rows that have name column set as `mtitle` or `description`, you could use `whereIn` method this way:

```
$default = Specific::where('status',1)
           ->whereIn('name',['mtitle','description'])->get();
```

You can now display value of those rows using loop:

```
foreach ($default as $item) {
    echo $item->name.' '.$item->value.' '.$item->key.' '.$item->status;
}
```

Comment: Thnk u for ur answer. but i have a doubt. how will i display value of each. is it like this $default['value']['mtitle'] ?

Comment: @Ammu I've updated my answer and changed `first` to `get` (haven't noticed it earlier)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query like this

```
$default = Specific::where('status',1)->where('name','mtitle')->get();
```

first() method will return only single first record with matching where conditions.

use 'get()' method to get all records.

you can also use `'paginate()'` for pagination if you have lots of records.

You can orWhere()

```
$default = Specific::where('status',1)->where('name','mtitle')->orWhere('name', 'mdescription')->get();
```

Comment: but this also retrieves only the row with name 'mtitle' right? i need to get the other row named 'mdescription' also.

Comment: Yes it will give only matching record.

Comment: @Ammu Updated Answer is that you need??